# Postgresql: Joining TimeSeries data with different time scaled: Weekly, Daily and Monthly

Tags: sql, postgresql, time-series

I've got data that comes in from the same sources at different rates. I'd like to plot the data (and do some thresholding etc) and the easiest way to do it would be treating it as timeseries data.

My data looks like:

```
SourceID, SubmissionTime,  Daily_Data
-------------------------------
ABC,    2020-01-01 10h32,  100
ABC,    2020-01-01 10h45,  101
ABC,    2020-01-02 09h01,  120
DEF,    2020-01-01 15h30,  123
```

and

```
SourceID, SubmissionTime,  Weekly_Data
-------------------------------
ABC,    2020-01-01 09h00,  Joe
ABC,    2020-01-08 09h21,  Soap
ABC,    2020-01-14 15h20,  Bill
```

The daily and weekly submissions are roughly a day or a week apart and are user inputs so there are gaps, delay, bad data etc. What I'd like to get out is something like:

```
SourceID, Daily_Date, Weekly_date, Weekly_datatime, Weekly_Data
-------------------------------
ABC,    2020-01-01, 2020-01-01 09h00,  101, Joe
ABC,    2020-01-02, 2020-01-01 09h00,  120, Joe
ABC,    2020-01-03, 2020-01-01 09h00,  122, Joe
...
ABC,    2020-01-07, 2020-01-01 09h00,  133, Joe
ABC,    2020-01-07, 2020-01-14 15h20,  145, Soap
```

Extracting the date is pretty trivial but how do I do a nearest datetime join for rows only after the weekly submission has occured. I've been doing something similar in TimscaleDB but this is on someone else's DB now who doesn't want extra extensions...

Comment: What do your results have to do with the sample data?  Where do the additional dates come from?  Where does 122 come from in the third row?

Comment: It's all imaginary data. The 122 is just to fill in gaps and to indicate a possible output, not to be 100% accurate. I though the concept was simple enough without needing to be pedantic about the dummy data.

Comment: . . Your imaginary data is my confusion.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. It's basically a "last object carried forward" problem where I did a straight up join of the daily/weekly/monthly tables and carried the last monthly/weekly observations forward to the daily time samples.

[More info here](http://www.joyofdata.de/blog/locf-linear-imputation-postgresql-tutorial/)

I created a function, an aggregate, and then ran the table through those:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fun(a FLOAT, b FLOAT)
RETURNS FLOAT
LANGUAGE SQL
AS '
  SELECT COALESCE(b, a)
';

select a,b,t,v,
    fun(t,v) as v_or_t
from tbl
order by a,b,t
;
```

and

```
create or replace function locf_s(a float, b float)
returns float
language sql
as '
  select coalesce(b, a)
';

drop aggregate if exists locf(float);
CREATE AGGREGATE locf(FLOAT) (
  SFUNC = locf_s,
  STYPE = FLOAT
);
```

and finally:

```
with weekly_data as (SELECT source_id, submissiontime, weekly_data from weekly_table)
select distinct on (source_id, submissiontime)
    source_id,
    submissiontime,
    daily_data,
    locf(weekly_data) over (PARTITION by source_id ORDER by submissiontime) as weekly_data,

from daily_table
join weekly_table on daily_table.source_id = weekly_table.source_id 
order by source_id, submissiontime desc;
```

this is just pseudo code, not exactly what I was using (since I multiple tables and weird data) so please forgive any faults, I'm hoping the idea comes across.